# RavenDB LINQ Query no longer works with new stable build (#616)

Tags: linq, ravendb

I'm using [RavenDBMembership](https://github.com/martijnboland/RavenDBMembership) Provider and after trying the latest [RavenDB new stable build (#616)](http://ravendb.net/news/41/new-stable-build-615) one LINQ query simply stopped working. This is the method:

```
private MembershipUserCollection FindUsers(
      Func<User, bool> predicate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
{
    var membershipUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();

    using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        var q = from u in session.Query<User>()
                where u.ApplicationName == ApplicationName //ApplicationName="MyApp"
                select u;

        IEnumerable<User> results;

        if (predicate != null)
        {
            results = q.Where(predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            results = q;
        }

        totalRecords = results.Count(); // Returns 0 but I do have 2 Users in the DB.

        // I also tried executing the query directly:
        // totalRecords = q.Count(); // Returns 0 but I do have 2 Users in the DB.

        var pagedUsers = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        foreach (var user in pagedUsers)
        {
            membershipUsers.Add(UserToMembershipUser(user));
        }
    }
    return membershipUsers;
}
```

That LINQ query above returns the Users correctly with the previous version of RavenDB I was using (#573). To test this, I removed the NuGet package (#616) and installed the old one (#573) and the query just works...

If I open RavenDB Studio I can see that I have Users and Roles correctly added to the database.

This is the User data:

```
{
  "ApplicationName": "MyApp",
  "Username": "leniel",
  "PasswordHash": "/L/7jv82VBSBeCDjH/gbwaKGQZGTV6na2FDiJpt6VDE=",
  "PasswordSalt": "/14i7C==",
  "FullName": null,
  "Email": "leniel@gmail.com",
  "DateCreated": "2012-02-02T05:02:22.0615234",
  "DateLastLogin": null,
  "Roles": [],
  "PasswordQuestion": null,
  "PasswordAnswer": null,
  "IsLockedOut": false,
  "IsOnline": false,
  "FailedPasswordAttempts": 0,
  "FailedPasswordAnswerAttempts": 0,
  "LastFailedPasswordAttempt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "Comment": null,
  "IsApproved": true
}
```

This is the User metadata:

```
{
  "Raven-Entity-Name": "Users",
  "Raven-Clr-Type": "RavenDBMembership.User, RavenDBMembership"
}
```

This is how a User is created:

```
public User()
{
   Roles = new List<string>();
   Id = "raven/authorization/users/"; // db assigns id
}
```

I read the [latest build page](http://ravendb.net/news/41/new-stable-build-615) but couldn't find a reason for this. Is there any breaking change that I'm unaware of?

For now I have to stick with stable build #573 in this specific MembershipProvider project since I don't have a clue about what's going on in the internals of RavenDB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this: `Func<User, bool> predicate`
You are passing it to the Query.Where, you are actually doing the evaluation in *memory*.
You need to use `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` for it to actually be a linq statement that can be processed as a query.

If this isn't the case, we would appreciate a failing test case.

**EDIT:**

Blah!
The reason is that your documents are named "raven/..."

And documents prefixed with Raven/ are NOT indexed.

Before, we did a case sensitive match for that, now we do a case insensitive match.

Don't name your documents with Raven/ prefix, that is reserved for system documents.

Comment: predicate is `null` in this case and so the flow goes to the else statement... How can I prepare a failing test case for you? I'd be happy to help in tracking what's the problem...

Comment: Somewhat related, but since your results local variable is declared as IEnumerable<User>, you're doing the Count, Skip, and Take calls all in memory (not sure if this is the cause or not).  Even without applying the Where clause, you've effectively done AsEnumerable :)  I'd probably try commenting out its declaration and the if/else bits, and just leave 'var results = q;' to see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @James: thanks for stopping by and commenting. I have also thought about this and just did this to test: `totalRecords = q.Count();` but it still returns 0... should return 2. Something is broken in RavenDB because this query worked just fine with stable build #573 as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Leniel, please create a failing test and send it to the mailing list.

Comment: Ayende, I have uploaded my current code at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/B-7JidmIYz4/xqTS367fNQUJ so that you can debug it and see what's happening.